# Domain Driven Design: where does the workflow logic lie?

Tags: workflow, domain-driven-design

In my project,i have workflow which operates on multiple entities to accomplish a business transaction. What is the best place to represent the workflow logic? currently i just create a "XXXManager" which is responsible for collaborating with entity objects to conclude a business transaction. Are there other options?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you're doing the right thing having something collaborate with multiple entities to get something done. The important thing is that each entity (and indeed each service) should have a [single responsibility](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).

The overarching workflow you're talking about is something that you can consider as a part of your Application Layer.

[According to Paul Gielens](http://weblogs.asp.net/pgielens/archive/2006/05/31/Applying-the-Application-Layer-in-Domain-Driven-Design.aspx) (paraphrased) The Application Layer’s responsibility is to digest the course-grained requests (messages/commands) to acheive a certain overarching goal. It does this by sending a message to Domain Services for fulfillment. It then also (optionally) decides to send notifications to the Infrastructure Service.

But then what is a 'Service'?! It's an overloaded term but one that's described well (again, [by Paul Gielens](http://weblogs.asp.net/pgielens/archive/2006/09/03/Domain-Model-Service.aspx))

You might also want to read about [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) for more ideas...

Comment: txn for the Onion Architecture reference, interesting article!

Answer (score 2):

Usually there is a domain object that should actually handle the control which is mistaken for an "entity".

Is there an instance of something that gets created as a result of this workflow?  If so, the workflow logic probably belongs in there.  Consider "Order" in the model below.

[alt text http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/4383/order.png](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/4383/order.png)

Oder is both a noun and a verb.  The "Order" is the object that created as a result of "Ordering".  Like any good class, it has both data and behavior (and I don't mean getters and setters).  The behavior is the dynamic process that goes with the data, i.e., the ordering workflow.  "Order" *is* the controller.

This is why OO was invented.

Comment: One might say that OO domain modeling is about nounification of verbs.

Comment: The image link is broken

Answer (score 1):

DDD might not be exactly about this sort of thing,  so I would suggest taking a look at the Service Layer architectural pattern.  Martin Fowler's book Patterns of Enterprise Architecture is a good book that will explain it.  You can find the description of the pattern on Fowler's web site as well.

Answer (score 0):

Creating Workflow systems can be a daunting prospect. Have you considered using [Workflow engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine)?

If I understand you correctly, you will need to create a manager which keeps track of the different transactions in the worklflow, related to user. There are probably other ways of doing it - but I've always used engines.

Answer (score 0):

To the great answers, I'd like to add ["domain events"](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) (link is just to one possible implementation) which is something Evans himself has come to put more focus on (["increased emphasis on events"](http://domaindrivendesign.org/library/evans_2009_1)).

Comment: A warning to anyone seeing this: Domain events handlers should not produce changes (side-effects) on the entity that raised the event.  This will significantly complicate the domain layer and carries a lot of hidden risk (infinite event loops, etc.)